# Control arrow keys in CLI app

Tags: go, terminal, command-line-interface

I would like to build a (golang) library that offers a number of options for user choice. My idea is to print the names of the options and highlight one as "active". Upon arrow keys (left and right or up and down) being pressed I would like to update the "selected" answer internally and visibly.

I know about `termbox` and [`tcell`](https://github.com/gdamore/tcell) and I also have checked projects like `peco`  and [`rat`](https://github.com/ericfreese/rat). All of them seem to build on the basic concept of a screen of some kind. Ideally I would like to keep the control in just the line the user is editing in his terminal without creating a fullscreen interaction. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: There are different libraries to do this depending on your operating system. Which OS are you using?

Comment: I'd aim for Linux and Mac, no interest in Windows currently ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: [This neat library called **climenu**](https://github.com/paulrademacher/climenu) practically does what I asked for. All the technical trickery needed is part of this code. Kudos to 
 [Paul Rademacher](https://github.com/paulrademacher)! I surely can adapt this to suit my needs.

Answer (score 1):

ncurses is one popular library for terminal control in Linux, and it has [Go bindings](https://github.com/rthornton128/goncurses) (also supports OSX and Windows). I have never used them, so I cannot vouch for them, but this is one way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The libraries I listed are somewhat more go-ish replacements of ncurses. As far as I have seen ncurses UIs they also seem to be window based, meaning they occupy all the terminal screen which is not what I strive for…

Comment: ncurses does what's suggested using `filter`, but goncurses does not appear to use that, and it does not appear to be in active development. You could clone `goncurses` and add interfaces to `filter`, etc.